# Can I create front-end editable user profile pages with Wordpress? How do I do it?

Tags: customization, front-end, profiles, user-meta

I'm trying to build a WP site where *using the front-end*, each user can:

1. Register through the front end using basic fields
2. Log in
3. Create their own profile page using multiple forms
4. Upload text, image and video data using profile forms
5. Create work related information (portfolios made up of images and video) that are separate from profile forms
6. be able to edit both profile and portfolio related information unique to their own profile only

So to summarise, we are talking about *2 separate types of information*:

A) user profile information that can be updated anytime after registration

B) Portfolio information that uses various media to create a front end profile for the user. This should be editable and updatable **via the front-end** after registration too.

So Is this possible to do with Wordperss? 
What tools and approaches would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Rarely do I answer question with simply a plugin recommendation - and I'd never recommend a commercial one - but since there's a really good plugin for the task of front end profiles/login and such out there, I cannot let it go unmentioned:

Check out [Theme-My-Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) by [Jeff Farthing](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/).

There ain't no better solution. It's well-written, flexible, timely updated and easily customized.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible with WordPress. Now lets look at your requirements one by one:

- You want users to register to be able to register on your site using front end.

For this you can redirect the login page to another custom page. Add a login form there and let users register from that page. If you don't want to go into all that coding, use the gravity forms.

- You want the users to create their profiles also.
  This can be accomplished by creating a separate template for the profile page. Create a form to take the entries for user profile. Populate the profile pages using that data. This is also easily done using Gravity forms.

However Gravity Forms are not free, so you can search for other form widgets that can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. I can write the code for login and registration forms actually. But can you tell me how I would handle portfolio creation for each individual type of user?  Would I create fields with gravity forms that map to custom post types in the backend?

Comment: That can be a good way to go about it. Add a custom post type of profile. There are plugins which will let you do these. I use Custom Post Type UI plugin. Then you can map the form in gravity form to this post type, so when a user makes its profile, it gets posted to your site as a post. You need to provide a template however for the post to be generated (or maybe there are available solutions which I might not be aware of).